# Adding an AAD group to Azure DevOps using the rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to do a put on

[https://team.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Graph/Memberships/{aadgp.GroupDescriptor}/vssgp.{GroupDescriptor}](https://team.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Graph/Memberships/%7Baadgp.GroupDescriptor%7D/vssgp.%7BGroupDescriptor%7D)

I can come up with the ADO group starting with vssgp. but I have been unable to come up with the AAD descriptor.

Calling AAD graph with

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'groupName'

doesnt appear to provide me anything that looks like that and calling

https://team.visualstudio.com/_apis/IdentityPicker/Identities?api-version=6.0-preview

with body

```
{
"query": "groupName",
"identityTypes": ["group"],
"operationScopes": ["ims", "source"]
}
```

doesnt give me anything that starts with aadgp.

I am running out of ideas and was hoping one of you may have done this already. I am unable to get all of the groups that have access to the org or team project as it will likely be a new group being added.

tia

Comment: Hi @john, I am glad to know you find the answer. Could you please accept your answer? This will help other developer to solve there similar issue. Thanks for your cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a bunch of calls.

- Get Azure graph to get Guid of group

  - GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq ‘GroupName’
- Get projects to determine id of project I need

  - GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0)
- Post to group entitlements to add the new group in

  - POST [https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/groupentitlements?api-version=6.0-preview.1)
- Get all groups from the org to get the aadgp value

  - GET [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.1-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=6.1-preview.1)
- Put on graph membership to add the group

  - PUT [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/memberships/{subjectDescriptor}/{containerDescriptor}?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/graph/memberships/%7BsubjectDescriptor%7D/%7BcontainerDescriptor%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.1)
- Delete on group entitlements to eliminate unneeded group entitlement

  - DELETE [https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/groupentitlements/{groupId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/groupentitlements/%7BgroupId%7D?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

Comment: I wanted to upvote the question but the fact that your name is john and current rep is 117 is just to beautiful :)